# How to pick up random image from an array of images and create a new image from jpg and put watermark?

Tags: php, arrays, random, watermark

I need to pick one random image from a preselected number of images from an array and use that image for imagecreatefromjpeg() function as base image for a watermark code
My code . The imagecreatefromjpeg() function is not creating a new image from the random adress generated .

```
$isrc1 ="c1.jpg";
$isrc2 ="c2.jpg";
$isrc3 ="c3.jpg";
$isrc4 ="c4.jpg";
$isrc5 ="c5.jpg";
$isrcarray = array($isrc1,$isrc2,$isrc3,$isrc4,$isrc5);

for ($i=0; $i<1; $i++) {
$it = $isrcarray[rand(0, count($isrcarray) - 1)] . "\n";

}

$box = @ImageTTFBBox(23,0,'arial.ttf',$userinfo[0]['name']);
$textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);
$x_finalpos = 255-($textwidth/2);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($it);
$font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0);
imagettftext($image, 23, 0, 101, 345, $font_color, 'arial.ttf', $userinfo[0]['name']);
ImageJPEG($image, $img);
ImageDestroy($image);
$img = "result.jpg";
```

Comment: So what doesn't work?  Your randomization could be much simplified by `shuffle($isrcarray)`

Comment: You could use `array_rand()` too.

Comment: You need to fix your questions, we have no clue what problem you have, secondly a minor mistake in your code, you set $img after you use it.

Comment: the randomize function function work when I test the output with echo $it; but imagecreatefromjpeg($it); dont take that value and image creation is not working .

Comment: The imagecreatefromjpeg() function is not creating a new image from the random value generated .

Comment: The images in your array are in the same directory as this PHP script?

Comment: yes they are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  $it=$isrcarray[array_rand($isrcarray)];
```

instead of,

```
  $it=$isrcarray[rand(0,count($isrcarray)-1)]."\n";
```